# Python pandas datetime -- changing only year under specific condition

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a data frame:
[image]

`Opening Date2` and `Closing Date2` are diatomite objects that I've created.

I would like to add another column as `Closing Date Actual`.

If `Change Closing Date` is True, I would like to add `Closing Date2` column into my new column with adding 1 year. If it is False, I would like to add as it is.

For example, in the new column, the first 5 rows will be:

```
2015-06-25
2015-03-19
2015-01-22
2014-04-04
2014-02-07
```

I tried to use list comprehensions, time delta functions but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Actual data that needs to be worked with would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

This requires version `0.17` (soon to be released or can install the release candiate with `conda install -c pandas pandas`).  See the [`DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) documentation for more.

```
df['Closing Date2'] = np.where(df['Change Closing Date'], 
                               df['Closing Date'] + pd.DateOffset(years=1),
                               df['Closing Date'])
```

In older versions you'd have to wrap `df['Closing Date']` in a `DatetimeIndex`, like this:

```
df['Closing Date2'] = np.where(df['Change Closing Date'], 
                               pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Closing Date']) + pd.DateOffset(years=1),
                               df['Closing Date'])
```